# Comparing String against array of String and counting the matches in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string-matching

I'm trying to compare a string (userInput) against an array of strings (groupA) to check how many of the items in groupA are present in the userInput.

```
var groupA = ["game of thrones", "star wars", "star trek" ]
var userInput = "My name is oliver i love game of thrones, star wars and star trek."
var count = 0

func checking() -> Int {
    for item in groupA {
        // alternative: not case sensitive
        if userInput.lowercased().range(of:item) != nil {
            count + 1
        }
    }

    return count
}

func Printer() {
     print(count)
}
```

Comment: To clarify, does the above code not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not very well designed, since you're using a lot of globals, but it will work with a few minor changes:

```
var groupA = ["game of thrones", "star wars", "star trek" ]
var userInput = "My name is oliver i love game of thrones, star wars and star trek."

var count = 0
func checking() -> Int {
    for item in groupA {

        // alternative: not case sensitive
        if userInput.lowercased().range(of:item) != nil {
            count += 1  //Make this `count += 1`
        }
    }
    return count
}
func printer() {
    print(count)
}

//Remember to call `checking()` and `printer()`
checking()
printer()
```

Also note that you should name all functions beginning with a lower-case letter, so `Printer()` should be `printer()`.

Consider this code instead:

```
import UIKit

var groupA = ["game of thrones", "star wars", "star trek" ]
var userInput = "My name is oliver i love game of thrones, star wars and star trek."

//The `checking` function has been rewritten as `countOccurerences(ofStringArray:inString)`, 
//and now takes parameters and returns a value.
func countOccurrences(ofStringArray stringArray: [String],  inString string: String) -> Int {
    var result = 0
    for item in stringArray {

        // alternative: not case sensitive
        if string.lowercased().range(of:item) != nil {
            result += 1
        }
    }
    return result
}

//And the `printer()` function now takes parameter as well.
func printer(_ count: Int) {
    print("count = \(count)")
}

//Here is the code to use those 2 functions after refactoring
let count = countOccurrences(ofStringArray: groupA, inString: userInput)
printer(count)
```

Comment: One improvement would be to only call `lowercased` once. Better yet, use `range(of:options;)` with `.caseInsensitive` (and probably `.diacriticInsensitive`).

Comment: True. I didn't try to completely rewrite the OP's code, but just provide a few pointers on how it could be improved.

Comment: @rmaddy have you ever benchmarked `.caseInsensitive` string comparison to see how much slower it is? My gut is that converting the string to lower case beforehand and then using regular string comparison would be faster, but haven't actually tested it.

Answer (score 0):

To make the above code work, you just need to change `count + 1` in line 18 to `count += 1` I've posted the complete code below.

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

var groupA = ["game of thrones", "star wars", "star trek" ]
var userInput = "My name is oliver i love game of thrones, star wars and star trek."


    var count = 0
    func checking() -> Int {


        for item in groupA {


            // alternative: not case sensitive
            if userInput.lowercased().range(of:item) != nil {
                count += 1
            }


        }

        return count
    }



    func Printer() {
        print(count)
    }

    checking()
    Printer()
```